# MATLAB: write polygons into kml file

Tags: matlab, kml

How can I write geospatial polygons into a .kml file with kmlwrite function?

After generating the poligons'vertives and defined their faces, I've plotted the polygons with the function patch:

```
pp = patch('Faces',faces,'Vertices',vertices);
```

and then I've defined the colors:

```
set(pp,'FaceColor','flat',...
       'FaceVertexCData',cdata,...
       'CDataMapping','direct',...
       'EdgeAlpha',.4,'EdgeColor','b')
```

Getting the following Matlab plot:

[image]

Now, I would like to visualize these polygons with Google Earth, but I don't know how.

I've tried the function

> kmlwrite

but I could pass to it only the polygons' vertices's coordinates, generating a kml file with all points and no polygon, as shown below:

[image]

Would you tell me how to store a kml file containing the polygons and their colors?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution of my problem in the MATLAB [KML ToolBox](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34694-kml-toolbox-v2-3) (in particular in the k.poly3 function).

Thanks to the author [Rafael Oliveira](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/115634).